# Exclude current week in Tableau automatically

Tags: tableau-api

I have set of data that is automatically updated each day with new lines.
On the other hand my graphs shows weekly/monthly data.

Is there any way to exclude current week/month, so that the graph can be automatically updated on the server, without me manually excluding and including weeks/months each time I have data for full week/month?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another option which I use regularly in my reports.

1. Index your date field by week, with a calculated field:
   `STR(DATEDIFF('week', [Date], today(), 'monday'))`

Note that here I have specified my weeks start on Monday, your requirement may be different.

2. Drag this field onto *filters* and `exclude` the value `0`, as in the index the current week will always be `0`, last week will be `1` etc.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is an untested example of a calculated field to exclude current week:

```
IF DATETRUNC('week',[your date field]) = DATETRUNC('week',NOW()) THEN
    'filter me'
ELSE
    'leave me'
END
```

Drag that calculated field to filters. In case you couldn't guess, exclude the 'filter me' value :)

Answer (score 1):

make a copy of your date field. Drop on filter, select condition tab, select by formula and drop this in the field:

```
datetrunc('week',[Order Date (copy)]) <> datetrunc('week',today())
```